# Joomla different layout with http:// and www

Tags: php, html, http, joomla, web

Why does my website look different when I type www. instead of http:// in the beginning of my domain name? oO
(some margins seem to be missing and h1 tags are bigger)
It took me days to figure out why the layout seemed to change randomly.
What is causing this how can I "fix" it?

Comment: Sounds like a different CSS is being used maybe? Doing any apache rewrite for css files?

Comment: I don't know. I changed some template css files but the changes didn't really apply. But I definitely did not change the margins or h1 tags.

Comment: In that case they might also be cached somewhere that you aren't aware of.

Comment: Well, take a look at my other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989221/joomla-ftp-files-updated-via-ftp-wont-update-in-browser  
Everything seems broken. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I do not know if you've tried it, perhaps it could be a cache problem? try clearing the cache of your browser or simply Ctrl + F5 in your browser. Also happens to me sometimes.

Comment: Holy f***, how is this possible. I cleaned my cache in firefox multiple time... Well Cztl+F5 did the job. :) Thanks.